# value error:Too many elements provided. Needed at most 4, but received 8

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in Data science.I wanted to use tensorflow in my data to optimize the theta parameter(variable) using gradient descent.

In the line which I wanted to turn theta to a constant vector I faced an error.

```
import csv
import tensorflow as tf
path=r"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\PRSA_data_2010.1.1-2014.12.31.csv"
f=open(path,encoding="utf8")
dataset=[]
header=f.readline().strip().split(',')
for line in f:
    line = line.split(',')
    dataset.append(line)
dataset = [d for d in dataset if d[5] !="NA"]
def feature(datum):
     feat=[1,float(datum[7]),float(datum[8]), float(datum[10])]
    return feat
x=[feature(d)for d in dataset]
y=[float(d[5]) for d in dataset]
y=tf.constant(y, shape=[len(y),1])
k=len(x[0])
def MSE(x,y,thetha):
   return tf.reduce_mean((tf.matmul(x,thetha)-y)**2)
theta=tf.Variable(tf.constant([0,0]*k,shape=[k,1]))
```

Then in the last line I got this error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-307fdd57da6c> in <module>
----> 1 theta=tf.Variable(tf.constant([0,0]*k,shape=[k,1]))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in constant_v1(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape)
    178   """
    179   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=verify_shape,
--> 180                         allow_broadcast=False)
    181 
    182 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    282       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(
    283           value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape,
--> 284           allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
    285   dtype_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=tensor_value.tensor.dtype)
    286   const_tensor = g.create_op(

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    526         raise ValueError(
    527             "Too many elements provided. Needed at most %d, but received %d" %
--> 528             (shape_size, nparray.size))
    529 
    530   tensor_proto = tensor_pb2.TensorProto(

ValueError: Too many elements provided. Needed at most 4, but received 8
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? It will have information for which line is causing the error.

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: @MyNamelsCalab i have edited it

Comment: What is the value of `k` when the error occurs? What happens if you execute `tf.constant([0,0]*k,shape=[k,1])` at a (Python) shell prompt, by itself not during program execution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have tensorflow but if it behaves like Numpy, then you have specified a shape that does not match the number of items in your value. Your Exception message implies that `k = 4` and you have specified a shape with four items yet your value (`[0,0]*k`) contains eight items:

```
In [13]: k = 4

In [14]: value = [0,0]*k

In [15]: value
Out[15]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

In [16]: np.asarray(value).reshape([k,1])
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-16-43f917d6ea82>", line 1, in <module>
    np.asarray(value).reshape([k,1])

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 8 into shape (4,1)
```